# Compiled kernel 4.19 will not boot: "Kernel panic not syncing : System is deadlocked on memory"

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, compiling, memory, deadlock

I am compiling kernel 4.19 on Ubuntu 14.04 because I have a assignment to add a system call, but when I try to boot this kernel there's a error:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: System is deadlocked on memory
```

Nothing happens after this message appears

[image: boot sequence stop at deadlock error]

1. I have compiled my kernel several times and installed the modules. No errors were shown in the old terminal.
2. I used GParted to enlarge my `/dev/sda1` and I have set up a swap area, all done.
3. The stock Ubuntu 14.04 kernel boots fine. I can log in and use smoothly.
4. Commands I used:

   ```
   sudo cp /boot/config-**** .config
   sudo make menuconfig               # I did not change anything here
   sudo make -j4
   sudo make modules_install
   sudo make install
   reboot
   ```
5. For the syscall, I just add a very simple helloworld in the `sys.c`:

   ```
   asmlinkage int sys_mysyscall(int arg){printk("hello %d\n",arg);return 0;}
   ```

   and I have added it in the `syscalls.h` and `syscall_64.tbl`.

Comment: Do you mean you patched the kernel, but the patch isn't provided in the question? . by the way. you should check (make help) about `make bindeb-pkg` it's easier to handle installed kernels then.

Comment: The helloworld syscall will only show when I reboot successfully and write another function and call it,but now ,I cannot reboot cause of some sort of deadlocked...what I addded in sys.c:`asmlinkage int sys_mysyscall(int arg){printk("hello %d\n",arg);return 0;}`

Comment: Apparently this can also be caused by a sort of race condition if you're using hotplug/dynamic memory (on a virtual machine). If that's the case, the solution is to increase the initial memory. For Ubuntu 22.04, it failed at 512MB but booted at 768MB. After boot it settled back to ~430MB

Comment: Just a hint: In my case, it did work when I gave the VM 512M of RAM, but I encountered that kernel panic when I increased to 1024M. Interestingly, 2048M do work. So there must be some other reason behind it than just too much/little memory.

Answer (score 11):

I have solved the problem by changing my memory to 4 G;

I download Ubuntu 18.04,kernel 4.20.1(stable),I didn't change anything and run it again,the same error still showed up so I tried to enlarge my memory again, it works.

I didn't realized it cause I have changed it from 1 G to 2 G before ,but it didn't worked, now everything is correct.

use:

```
wjrforcyber@wjr:~$ uname -a
```

it shows:

```
Linux wjr 4.20.1 #1 SMP Fri Jan 11 20:57:27 CST 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

success!

Comment: Excellent. I was facing the same issue. It solved as well.

Comment: Thanks. This saved my day!

Comment: Thanks! FTR, same here when running QEMU image, apparently by default it allocates too small amount of memory, so adding a `-m 2G` parameter fixed the problem.

Comment: I faced the same issue and stumbled upon this post. I enlarged memory given to the machine straight to 4 Gb, but nothing happened. Then, while thinking "Screw it", I gave it bizzare 8 gigs of RAM, and it booted. Is it possible that you need to change the amount of memory two times?

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue trying to install Debian as a Proxmox VM...

However the issue was simply that I had downloaded the incorrect Debian iso. I downloaded the i386 version when I actually needed the amd64 version.

Enter `uname -m` in the shell and it will return your architecture type.

Comment: Did you read that OP solved their problem 2.5 years ago (adding RAM) ?

Comment: @MC68020 That doesn't really matter. We don't really answer questions for the OP, we answer as a way of collecting a library of useful solutions that can help the OP _and_ the hundreds of thousands of users who might see the question in the future. We actually actively encourage people answering old questions or editing existing answers to make them better. Granted, this does feel like a bit of an edge case, but if Nick encountered this, others might as well, so we don't lose anything by having the answer here.

Comment: Thank you, @terdon. That was my exact intent when adding an answer here.