# System is deadlocked on memory

Tags: kernel, boot, upgrade, kernel-panic, deadlock

I've upgraded my kernel on LinuxLite 4.8 from 4.15.0-74-generic to 5.4.30 (unpatched) using the commands:

```
sudo cp /boot/config-$(uname -r) .config
sudo make menuconfig
sudo make
sudo make modules_install
sudo make install
reboot
```

I just saved the standard settings in menuconfig without changing anything. After rebooting I faced the following error:

> end Kernel panic - not syncing: System is deadlocked on memory

Would anyone know how to solve this?

I already found [Compiled kernel 4.19 will not boot: "Kernel panic not syncing : System is deadlocked on memory"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/492667/compiled-kernel-4-19-will-not-boot-kernel-panic-not-syncing-system-is-deadlo) question, but I cannot afford to use 4 GB of RAM as the motherboard only supports a maximum of 2 GB (which is what I am using currently). I can still boot using the older kernel version.

Thanks in advance!